# How to optimize 2 loops

Tags: r

I am running a simulation trying to find the probability of something taking place in a number of binomial trials. I start with specifying the data

```
iter=5000
data=data.frame(prob=runif(300), value=runif(300))
data<-data[sample(nrow(data), iter, replace=T),]
```

then I add the trials

```
cols <- c("one","two","three","four","five","six",
          "seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve")
data[,cols] <- NA
```

`one` contains the results of only one binomial trials, `two` contains the results of two binomial trials and so on. If a binomial event takes place in any of the `one`, `two`, `three`, ..., `twelve`, the cell is marked 1 else 0.

Then I run the trials for `iter=5000` simulations

```
for (col in 3:14) {
  for (i in 1:iter) if (sum(rbinom((col-2),1,data[i,1]))>0) data[i,col]<-1 else data[i,col]<-0
}
```

Then I evaluate the `mean(data$value[data$one==0]` till ...  `mean(data$value[data$twelve==0]`

My problem is that the simulation code takes forever for `iter>15000`.

```
  for (col in 3:14) {
    for (i in 1:iter)
      data[i,col] <- if (sum(rbinom((col-2),1,data[i,1]))>0) 1 else 0
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I get an error running your first double for loop up there: `Error in if (sum(rbinom((col - 2), 1, data[i, 1])) > 0) 1 else 0 : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: Also look at the vectorized version of `if...else`. The function is named `ifelse()`. I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do with this code, but I can almost assure you we can get rid of at least one for loop, if not both of them with vectorized solutions which will run MUCH faster.

Comment: `prob` has to be `runif(300)`, not `rnorm(300)` since it is a probability.

Comment: Your algorithm seems to be O(n^2) in `iter`.  I'm not sure why, though, because there is only a single loop over `iter`.  I'm guessing it has to do with copying data around.  Extrapolating from timings I ran, 15000 would take my computer about half an hour.

Comment: Sorry guys. My bad. I corrected the code and runs OK but very slow. I need to do this on a very large set about 500.000 and multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sim2 <- function(iter) {
    dat <- data.frame(prob=runif(300), value=runif(300))
    dat <- dat[sample(nrow(dat), iter, replace=TRUE),]
    cols <- c("one","two","three","four","five","six",
              "seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve")
    dat[,cols] <- 0

    for (col in 3:14) {
        dat[,col] <- as.numeric(vapply(dat[,1],
                                       function(p) {sum(rbinom((col-2), 1, p))>0},
                                       FUN.VALUE = TRUE))
    }
    vapply(3:14, function(col) {mean(dat$value[dat[,col]==0])}, FUN.VALUE=1)
}
```

For `iter` of 16000, this runs in 2.29s on my machine, compared to an (estimated) 1781s for the ordering in your original algorithm.  In general, don't assign individual elements in the data frame when you can assign the whole column at once.  There may be more improvements possible, but I'll stop at >750x speedup (and changing the algorithm from running time of O(n^2) to O(n)).